# How can I add headings to my protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reports?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

I am sharing my spec file, the generated report contains only 'through Gmail Account' text but I want to add 'Password pop up' text and many other headings also. I tried by adding one more 'it' block containg passoword code but my code was not working.

I want to make report shows the headings for all test cases.

My spec file is:

```
describe('Login', function () {
    afterEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;     });
    it(' through Gmail Account', function () {  
        var GM = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  
        browser.get("http://folio3.github.io/eCareVault/#");
        //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        var gmail = element(by.css('.ggl>img'));
        browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(gmail), 5000);
        gmail.click();               
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
        element(by.id("Email")).click();
        element(by.id("Email")).sendKeys('cc0@gmail.com');
        element(by.id("next")).click();
        element(by.id("Passwd")).click();
        element(by.id("Passwd")).sendKeys('click123');
        element(by.id("signIn")).click();
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
//Password popup
       var Password = element(by.model("anyvalue"));
       browser.wait(GM.visibilityOf(Password), 10000);
       Password.sendKeys("123");
       element(by.id("submit")).click();
       element(by.css('.overview' )).click();
       element(by.css('.edit' )).click();       element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/form/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')).click().clear().sendKeys('bob');    
        });
    }); 
});
```